# "OAuth is not defined"

Tags: cordova, oauth, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

Cordova, Ionic Framework, and OAuth-io plugin.

`npm install -g cordova ionic
ionic start myApp tabs
cordova plugin add https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-phonegap
ionic serve`

At this point looking at your browser console you'll get a message about OAuth beind undefined, and `console.log(OAuth)` seems to agree. Thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the emulator instead, Cordova features don't work in a normal browser. This will add a platform, and then allow you to emulate it using iOS (assuming you have the simulators and Xcode setup). You could replace ios with android. It also will live reload in the emulator for you with the -l flag.

```
ionic platform add ios
ionic emulate ios -l -c
```

Comment: Interesting, how does one tell if a third party plugin makes use of something in cordova.js or not? No way to fake this when using serve?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but when you pull in a Cordova plugin it can only be loaded in an emulator. If you pull in some third party code, it should inform you that you'll need to use it with Cordova. Corodva is meant to bridge between a native platform (iOS/Android/etc) and a WebView (with a JavaScript API to reach native aspects).